# Linking GLIBC statically and proprietary software licensing

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, glibc, lgpl

I have basic understanding problem with open source and licenses. Could someone please clarify some questions for the below scenario. Excuse me if it is very basic

1. I'm writing a proprietary software in which i plan to use some open source libraries. I will also need glibc and a C compiler, but did not want to use the default gcc toolchain from my OS, so built my own using crosstools-ng
2. Now in ct-ng, i guess the libstdc++ library gets linked statically(which is for c++ and i won't be using that in most case i guess) but from my toolchain configuration is my libc statically or dynamically linked? If that is the case, given that glibc is LGPL, and that i can link it to my proprietary software, will this static linking cause any issues to me wrt licensing? Can my software still be close sourced? or do i have to release the compiled objects.

My toolchain configuration is below, from this could someone point to me if glibc is statically or dynamically linked?

```
Target: x86_64-some-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/src/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/.build/src/gcc-4.4.7/configure --build=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-some-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/obj/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/x86_64-some-linux-gnu --with-sysroot=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/obj/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG 1.15.3' --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libmudflap --enable-libgomp --enable-libssp --with-gmp=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/src/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/.build/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-mpfr=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/src/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/.build/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-ppl=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/src/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/.build/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-cloog=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/src/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/.build/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --with-long-double-128 --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/home/balravin/tools/platform/x86/obj/gnu/gcc/4.4.7/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/x86_64-some-linux-gnu/sysroot --enable-c99 --enable-long-long
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 (crosstool-NG 1.15.3)
```

Comment: If you are interested, I have created a site proposal on area51 for everything related to open source: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing?referrer=8PFLrZ3ydnhFtbu7jPSDPA2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many reasons, both legal and technical, to make `libc.so` dynamically linked.

On the legal side, the [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html) license of GNU libc requires you to permit your users to enhance their libc; so if you sell a proprietary software which is statically linked (a technically bad idea), you need to give the means to your user to relink it to a better version of libc; concretely you'll probably need to also give the `*.o` object of your software.

On the technical side, dynamically linking `libc.so` is nearly required by all features taking indirectly advantage of `libdl.so` or of `ld.so` -i.e. using dynamic linking-, in particular the NSS related functions (like `getpwent` and `getaddrinfo` and many others, see [nsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) & [nss(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nss.5.html)). Also, dynamically linking libc is much more efficient (the RAM is nearly shared by all processes using `libc.so` and the executable size is smaller; and most importantly, upgrading `libc.so` is easier).

BTW, did your company considered making your Linux software free (as in speech)? It does have many advantages, and many companies are choosing the open source route.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I just made some corrections to my question. Only libstdc++ is linked statically. However, i understand your response when i comes to linking libc statically, as you say i should then consider releasing the object / linking dynamically so that users of my software can recompile with a newer libc. Making some portion of my linux software open-source is something that i'm considering(ofcourse apart from the opensource lib which is anyway opensource), but not the entire source, there will be some proprietary code.

Comment: The LGPL still requires facilitating the upgrade of any LGPL-ed library you link with.

Comment: Dynamic linking isn't always the way. When you're write a soft with MinGW, upon being compiled and run under Windows it is have a habit to complain about missing *libc*. If you're write a small technical program that don't need an own directory(i.e. BIOS updater), the preferred choice would be to compile a *libc* statically.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning in the answer that if there are ever any bugs or security vulnerabilities in libc, software that statically links it will need to be re-linked and re-released by the software vendor. Software that dynamically links it will automatically take advantage of libc updates shipped by the OS vendor.

Comment: I wonder where builtin libc functions fit into this? I mean gcc replaces `memcpy` with built in code for sizes less than 8192 bytes. That leaves the user no way of upgrading the library. It's effectively like statically liking `memcpy`.

Comment: @Zboson that code isn't actually from glibc so there's no legal issue (gcc has a license exception for when your program contains libgcc code).