# Use sin function of different glibc versions without compiling the entire glibc?

Tags: c++, c, glibc, math.h

I want to try with different `glibc`'s `sin` functions. Is their a way to use `sin` function of different `glibc` versions without compiling the entire `glibc`?

i have downloaded different versions of `glibcs` on my virtual ubuntu machine.  I do find the source of `sin` function. Is there a way to use the different 'sin' without compiling its full glibc?

Comment: Depending on how much it depends on, you can just copy it to a file in your project.

Comment: @linuxios Oh, it does depends on a lot: #include <errno.h>
#include "endian.h"
#include "mydefs.h"
#include "usncs.h"
#include "MathLib.h"
#include <math_private.h>
#include <fenv.h>

Comment: I mean the specific function. What functions does it call?

Comment: Just statically link your executable. It will link only the required functions! (But there are some pitfalls, e.g. NSS).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch What are the potential pitfalls, pls?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11693411/841108

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Sorry but what do you mean by  "link only the required functions"?  Already, there are a bunch of header files in the source file of 'sin' that we have almost no clue where to find them. In addition, the are a bunch of macros in the source file. In particular,  the function 'sin' does not exist anywhere in the source file of 'sin' (s_sin.c). They use macros and we have totally no clue which function to call... Do you mean I can just use gcc -c -o a.out <my_file_invoking_sin> <source_of_sin> ? Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it. BTW, look also inside [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/). Notice that you don't [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) *source* files but only [*object files*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file). And explain what different `sin` functions did you find in *glibc*

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice is to copy the function code into your sources and fill in all the missing functionality - functions that sin calls, all (if any) constants etc. Might not be a simple task